# How are fieldnames supposed to be used in numpy structured arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here is a simple example where I want to represent a multidimensional array **r0** describing cartesian coordinates (x, y, z):

```
import numpy as np

r0 = np.random.random((3, 2, 1000))
r1 = {'x': r0[0], 'y': r0[1], 'y': r0[2]}
r2 = np.array(r0, dtype=[('x', float), ('y', float), ('z', float)])

for r in [r0[0], r1['x'], r2['x']]:
    print('{:}:\t{:} bytes'.format(r.shape, r.nbytes))
```

This results in:

```
(2, 1000):      16000 bytes
(2, 1000):      16000 bytes
(3, 2, 1000):   48000 bytes
```

I fail to undertand what `r2['x']` is doing. Intuitively I'd be able to access elements in **r2** like I would do in the dict **r1**.

I'm not 100% I even require numpy structured arrays for my use case but my arrays can become quite large and the dimensionality is quite high so I'd think having named structured arrays would improve code maintainability. I suspect for memory efficiency **r0** is most efficient, for readability **r1** might be slightly better. I was hoping **r2** would be a best of both worlds data structure.

Comment: Your `r1` array is a good solution no ? I guess that you've misunderstood how works numpy structured array. Actually you copy `r0` in each field, maybe you want something like this `r2 = np.array([(r0[0],r0[1],r0[2])], dtype=[('x', float, (2,1000)), ('y', float, (2,1000)), ('z', float, (2,1000))])`, but I don't get how it will be more useful than `r1`.

Comment: yes, the dict option is a fine solution though more/less equivalent to __r0__, but I'm just wondering what is the purpose of naming structured arrays. Why is it that specifying r0[0] to 'x' in an nd.array seems to copy the whole array? I could imagine a solution where one could index a structured array __r2__ such that r2[0] == r2['x'], r2[1]==r2['y'], r2[2]==r2['z'], basically just applying a named label to the multidimensional array __r0__

Comment: There is a whole page in `numpy` docs on 'structured arrays'.  Your `r2` construction is wrong.  The data should be supplied as a list of tuples.  I wouldn't use a steuctured array just for the column labeling convenience.

Comment: Will you have need to do math across coordinates?  For example `np.sum(r1, axis=0)`, or adding value to all 3.  In cases like that the `r1` 3d array is better.  You can't do math across the fields of a structured array.  You can do `r2['x']+r2['y']`, but not `sum`.  Practice with some small arrays where you can examine all values.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html

Comment: yeah generall sums dot and cross products are involved in which case specifying an axes may be prefered but sometimes its nice to read the index in x, y, and z rather than 0, 1, 2, especially if comparing 3 x,y,z vectors v1, v2, v3, then you end up getting v[0,0,:], v[0,1,:] etc. I think for now the original multidimensional array is the most sensible for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of recarrays and structured arrays as `shape=(nrows,)` and `dtype=[('fname1', ftype1, 'fname2', ftype2, 'fname3', ftype3)]`.  When your array dimension is > 2, your fields will use nd.arrays to retain the shape of the other dimensions.

You may or may not want a structured array for your use case (with more than 2 dimensions/axes). It's hard to say without knowing the details of your data. They are useful for 2 situations: 1) when you need an array of compound data (mix of floats, ints, strings, etc), and 2) when you want to access a "column" of data by the field/column name (using `arr['x']` instead of `arr[0]`). (Regarding `r1` dictionary vs a structured array, I find it's easier to use NumPy arrays instead of dictionaries for this kind of data.)

Your construction of `r2[]` copied all of the `r0[]` data into each field. That's why it's larger than `r0` and `r1`.

@obchardon's suggestion might be what you want. I combined it with your answer (to create `r3[]`), and added some statements to compare shape and dytpe for `r2` and `r3`. Also, I reduced the `a2` dimensions and used `np.arange()` so it's easier to "see" which values are assigned to each field. When you do this, `r3['x']` will be the same as `r0[0]` (and `r1['x']`). See below:

```
import numpy as np

a0, a1, a2 = 3, 2, 10
r0 = np.arange(a0*a1*a2).reshape(a0,a1,a2)

r1 = {'x': r0[0], 'y': r0[1], 'y': r0[2]}
r2 = np.array(r0, dtype=[('x', float), ('y', float), ('z', float)])
print(r2.shape, r2.dtype)
r3 = np.array([(r0[0],r0[1],r0[2])], dtype=[('x', float, (a1,a2)), ('y', float, (a1,a2)), ('z', float, (a1,a2))])
print(r3.shape, r3.dtype)

for r in [r0[0], r1['x'], r2['x'], r3['x']]:
    print('{:}:\t{:} bytes'.format(r.shape, r.nbytes))
```

Resulting shapes and dtypes:

```
r2.shape: (3, 2, 10) 
r2.dtype: [('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')]
r3.shape: (1,) 
r3.dtype: [('x', '<f8', (2, 10)), ('y', '<f8', (2, 10)), ('z', '<f8', (2, 10))]
```